# Failed to deploy springBoot generated war in JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am trying to deploy a war on jboss eap6 generated by springBoot . I created the `jboss-web.xml` file under the `WEB-INF` directory and  have set **server.servlet-path = /*** in `application.properties` file .

but while deploying the war i am getting following error

```
jboss.deployment.unit."shoppingApp.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "shoppingApp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:206)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
```

application.properties

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "test"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8081

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.devtools.restart.exclude=static/**,templates/**

server.servlet-path = /*
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

war{
    archiveName = 'shoppingApp.war'
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    //compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'


    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

}
```

after removing jersey dependency i'm getting following error

```
21:14:33,016 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."shoppingApp.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."shoppingApp.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "shoppingApp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
```

after changing the build to update logback version 
ext['logback.version'] = '1.1.9'
getting following error

```
jboss.deployment.unit."shoppingApp.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "shoppingApp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar
```

Comment: Do you have jersey jars in your app ? if so, delete them.

Comment: deleted the jersey jars getting Deployment error processing SCI for jar: logback-classic-1.1.11.jar

Comment: downgrade logback.version to 1.1.9   . https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8354

Comment: after changing the buildscript getting Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar

Comment: Try first to exclude tomcat-embed-websocket.jar . If no fix, try the latest version of tomcat embeded websocket..

Comment: You are creating a war file that you are deploying. With that you need to tell grade that the tomcat dependencies are provided and not compile time. Else those will be packaged as part of your war you don't want that. Also downgrading Logback shouldn't be needed as you are on boot 1.5 which ships with a newer logback (afaik). Also when deploying you probably want to change class loading for your app to parent-last (or whatever that is called on Jobs nowadays).